# Randomize all entries from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, model

I have a product-model with a total of ~40 entries.

In one of my views I want to print all of these entries. I do that via something like

```
@products = Product.all
```

and in my view I iterate over the entries as so

```
@products.each do |p|
//Do some magic display
```

'Problem' now is that I further want to randomize what entry gets shown first. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `@products = Product.order("RANDOM()")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to do something like `@products = Product.order("RANDOM()")`

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working quite well :)
Gonna accept your answer in a couple minutes.

Comment: @PhilM. Thanks, I am glad that I can help. Keep posting and learning

Comment: After switching from SQLite to Mysql I noticed the "RANDOM()" function is SQLite-specific.

Mysql requires tit to be RAND().